# How to do the pagination when read xml data by LINQ

Tags: c#, xml, linq, pagination

this below way i am reading xml data with linq. now show what to do to fetch data with pagination

```
XDocument document = XDocument.Load(@"c:\users\tridip\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\WindowsFormsApplication5\WindowsFormsApplication5\Orders.xml");
            var books = from r in document.Descendants("Orders")
            select new
            {
                OrderID = r.Element("OrderID").Value,
                CustomerID = r.Element("CustomerID").Value,
                EmployeeID = r.Element("EmployeeID").Value,
            };
```

i got one sample script but it look bit different. here is the code

```
var limit=100;

var items = xmldoc.Descendants("whatevernodename")
           .Select(node => node.Value.ToString())
           .Skip(limit)
           .Take(100)
           .ToList();
```

if see the above code there u can see all fields will return but this below way i need to specify fields

```
select new
            {
                OrderID = r.Element("OrderID").Value,
                CustomerID = r.Element("CustomerID").Value,
                EmployeeID = r.Element("EmployeeID").Value,
            };
```

and also show me how to specify order by order id ASC or DESC

thanks

Comment: You already have pagination logic by using `Skip()` then `Take()`, what's the problem with that?

Comment: Please be more specific. According to Asc use -> OrderBy. For Desc use OrderByDesc

Comment: when using `Skip() and Take()` then how could i specify to fetch data for only few fields called `OrderID, CustomerID, EmployeeID`. please guide me with sample code or modify my code. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can incrementally build your LINQ-to-XML query, for example :

```
//setup basic query
var query = from r in document.Descendants("Orders")
            select new
            {
                OrderID = r.Element("OrderID").Value,
                CustomerID = r.Element("CustomerID").Value,
                EmployeeID = r.Element("EmployeeID").Value,
            };

//setup query result ordering,
//assume we have variable to determine ordering mode : bool isDesc = true/false
if (isDesc) query = query.OrderByDescending(o => o.OrderID);
else query = query.OrderBy(o => o.OrderID);

//setup pagination, 
//f.e displaying result for page 2 where each page displays 100 data
var page = 2;
var pageSize = 100;
query = query.Skip(page - 1*pageSize).Take(pageSize);

//execute the query to get the actual result
var items = query.ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

so My Updated code as follows which i fixed after getting answer from @Har07.

```
XDocument document = XDocument.Load(@"c:\users\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\WindowsFormsApplication5\WindowsFormsApplication5\Orders.xml");
            bool isDesc = true;
            //setup basic query
            var query = from r in document.Descendants("Orders")
            select new
            {
                OrderID = r.Element("OrderID").Value,
                CustomerID = r.Element("CustomerID").Value,
                EmployeeID = r.Element("EmployeeID").Value,
            };

            //setup query result ordering,
            //assume we have variable to determine ordering mode : bool isDesc = true/false
            if (isDesc) query = query.OrderByDescending(o => o.OrderID);
            else query = query.OrderBy(o => o.OrderID);

            //setup pagination, 
            //f.e displaying result for page 2 where each page displays 100 data
            var page = 1;
            var pageSize = 5;
            query = query.Skip(page - 1 * pageSize).Take(pageSize);

            //execute the query to get the actual result
            //var items = query.ToList();
            dataGridView1.DataSource = query.ToList();
```